# Search showing deleted items in results

Tags: 2007, search-results

We have a public facing site. One of the pages was deleted , that still shows up in the search results even after multiple FULL CRAWL. When i browse to the URL from the search results it takes me to the 404 page . I check the crawl log it says this URL is crawled

I checked the recycle bin, the item is not there.

The last option for me is to do a full index reset , which i am not planning to do as i have other content sources .

The question here is once the item is deleted, how can that be crawled by the Crawler ?

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: You mentioned you have many content sources, did you do a full crawl in all of them?

Comment: No, i did only on one , Does that make an impact?

Comment: It depends on how it is configured, try doing a full crawl on every content source.

Comment: I did full crawl on all the content sources but it still shows

Comment: Just noticed this is 2007. I can't remember if there was the Search Result Removal option in the SSP Search Settings.

Comment: Yes Matt, There is an option, right now i was using that . But was curious to know the inner workings

Comment: Do you get any errors trying to crawl the content? Also found a post for 2010, don't know if it is the same behavior but could shed some light into the issue. [http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2011/01/20/managing-crawl-deletion-policies-for-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx]